# One item per line (row) in timeline? - Vis.js

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

Is there a way to always have one item per line in the timeline? I don't want two or more items to share the same line, whatever the dates are.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any answer for this yet? I still need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use groups, or if you're already using those for another purpose, you have to use subgroups.
[Here's the official documentation for items, groups and subgroups](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#items) (I'm assuming the website isn't gonna expire anytime soon... again...).

**If you can use groups**

Specify a different group for every item. You can set the group's `content` as an empty string, if you don't want to have a label for it on the left side of the Timeline.
If you want to arrange the groups in a specific way, specify an ordering function as the Timeline's options' `groupOrder` property. Example:

```
var options = {
    // other properties...
    groupOrder: function (a, b) {
        if(a.content > b.content)// alphabetic order
            return 1;
        else if(a.content < b.content)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

**If you have to use subgroups**

When you create an item, put it in the group it belongs to but also specify for it the `subgroup` property so that it's unique, like the item's `id`. For example, you can use the id itself, or add a prefix or suffix to it.
In the Timeline's options, set the `stack` and `stackSubgroups` properties to `true`.
In each group, set the `subgroupStack` property to `true` and specify an ordering function as the group's `subgroupOrder` property. Example:

```
var group = {
    id: 1,
    content: 'example group',
    subgroupStack: true,
    subgroupOrder: function(a, b) {
        var tmp = a.start.getTime() - b.start.getTime();
        return tmp === 0 ? parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id) : tmp;

        // if the start dates are the same, I compare the items' ids.
        // this is because due to a bug (I guess) the ordering of items
        // that return 0 in the ordering function might "flicker" in certain
        // situations. if you want to order the items alphabetically in that
        // case, compare their "content" property, or whatever other
        // property you want.
    }
};
```

Comment: The website did in fact expire "soon"